# URL query string convention for multiple sort

Tags: url, format, query-string

I have a RESTful web application that supports multiple sort fields on a collection of items. Is there a common convention for encoding these sort fields into the query string of a URL? I'm considering a pattern like the following:

```
http://myapp.com/books?sort=author:asc,datepublished:desc&count=12
```

This would sort the collection of books by author and then by date published.

Basically, I need a convenient way for the name-value pairs in my query string to have name-value pairs of their own. I'll need to do something similar to the above example for filter parameters, too.

Does Rails or ASP.NET MVC have a pattern for this? Are there other frameworks that have established ways for dealing with this issue? I'd rather use a familiar format than roll my own.

I'd also prefer a format that uses as little URL percent-encoding as possible.

Comment: Good question -- I've wondered the same thing myself.

Comment: It looks like you're making a JSON-ish format; which I would avoid because someone may interpret it -as- JSON, in which case the notion of ordering is lost.

Comment: Good point, Tom. That's why I'm asking for feedback!

Comment: I've updated my sample pattern to remove the braces, per Tom's feedback. They weren't necessary anyway.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've done this before using the standard SQL sorting syntax.  There are numerous parsing functions and techniques out there.

```
http://myapp.com/books?sort=author asc,datepublished desc&count=12
```

which would be encoded to

```
http://myapp.com/books?sort=author+asc,datepublished+desc&count=12
```

Comment: This is a good way to go as it is also compatible with Solr, a widely-used open-source search engine.

Comment: +1, Plus Comma list is probably better than Comma Comma list.

Comment: Simple. I like it. We have a winner!

Comment: If you use those values directly you'll have a pretty security hole for SQL-injection. I'm warning you ;)

Comment: @BYK, good point, be sure to scrub your results before passing them to SQL, if your planning that.

Answer (score 20):

For REST, I prefer a more intuitive syntax:

`http://myapp.com/books?sort=author,-datepublished&count=12`

Easy to remember... (means: ORDER BY author ASC, datepublished DESC)

note: removed "+" prefix because is a reserved word

Comment: what does + and  - stand for ?
i mean what is asc and what i desc.

Comment: + is a special character in URL and will be encoded. I wonder how you tackled that

Comment: @pm1090: I edited to remove "+" plus sign, as you say is special character...

Answer (score 1):

What about a fully PHP compliant version like this one:

```
http://myapp.com/books?sort[0][name]=author&sort[0][dir]=asc&sort[1][name]=datepublished&sort[1][dir]=desc&count=12
```

A bit longer but much convinient and as I've said, compliant with PHP. ASP.NET might have implemented support for this format also.

This will create an array, *sort*, directly where each element of sort has a *name* and *dir* property.