# Add comma seperated value to URL based on the checked box using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, checkbox

Based on the question below and example , I wanted to achieved that result based on the clicked box with the name and value to be added on the url.example of that is based on the checked box the url output https://test.com/searchnewdata?Year=2020,2019,2018&Model=EcoSport,Edge.

## Basic JS basis

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
       //var url="http://example.com/results?choice=choice2&choice=choice4"
       var url="http://example.com/results?choice=";
       var flag=false;
     $("input:checkbox[name=choice]:checked").each(function(){
         if(!flag)
         {
           url=url+$(this).val();
           flag=true;// To trace if first query string added
         }
         else
         {
             url=url+"&choice="+$(this).val();
         }         
      });
        alert(url);
   });
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<form name="search_something" action=/results method="get">
<text>Year</text>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2019">2019<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2018">2018<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2017">2017<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2016">2016<p>




   <text>Model</text>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice1">BMW<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice2">Ecosport<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice3">Acura<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice4">Edge<p>
   <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search">

  </form>
```

## Desired Result for example based on the checked box.

https://test.com/searchnewdata?Year=2020,2019,2018&Model=EcoSport,Edge

[image: Checkbox Screenshot]

Comment: What's not working in whatever you've tried so far? Also I recommend [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) interface and its searchParams instead of manual URL generation.

Comment: can you post your answer using that way so i can upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URI spec, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), specifies that URI path components should not contain unencoded reserved characters and comma is one of those reserved characters. Using the [`URL` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) will take care of this encoding and decoding for you.

Here is a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const url = new URL("http://example.com/results");

  $("#btnSearch").click(function() {
    setSearchParams('Year');
    setSearchParams('Make');
    console.log(url);
  });

  function setSearchParams(name) {
    let searchParams = [];

    $(`input:checkbox[name=${name}]:checked`).each(function() {
      searchParams = [...searchParams, $(this).val()];
    });

    searchParams.length ? url.searchParams.set(name, searchParams.join()) : url.searchParams.delete(name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="search_something" action=/results method="get">

  <text>Year</text><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2019">2019<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2018">2018<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2017">2017<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Year" value="2016">2016<br>

  <text>Model</text><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice1">BMW<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice2">Ecosport<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice3">Acura<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Make" value="choice4">Edge<br>
  <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search">

</form>
```

Now if you want to get the search params. Use `url.searchParams.get('Year')` and it will automatically decode the URL to give you the data as comma-separated.

Comment: See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828831/9739129) to know why you shouldn't use comma in your URL. You can also read the link I provided in the answer (Section 2.2) for the best practice when it comes to reserved characters in the URL.

Comment: If I only select Year only it should not return this output 
Not :  http://example.com/results?Year=2019%2C2018&Make="
The output should be : Not :  http://example.com/results?Year=2019%2C2018 , no Make cause i did not select make

Comment: In your current code it returns example.com/results?Year=2019%2C2018&Make="

There should be no Make=" ,if its not selected

Comment: are you still there sir ?

Comment: I am okay with the(Section 2.2) issue. My concern is that if I dont select Make it should not include Make on the output url like this http://example.com/results?Year=2019%2C2018&Make= , there should no Make = , the correct ouput if i dont select make should be http://example.com/results?Year=2019%2C2018%2C2017

Comment: @Mr.RajivKumar - I have already updated the answer to take care of that

Comment: Hi sir i have a question , are you still there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198869/discussion-between-mr-rajiv-kumar-and-nash11).

Comment: can we talk in chat ?

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this** Live demo [link](http://tpcg.io/UV1IHI) (click on preview to start demo)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
      var yearArray = []; 
      $("input:checkbox[name=Year]:checked").each(function(){
         yearArray.push($(this).val());
       });
      var makeArray = []; 
      $("input:checkbox[name=Make]:checked").each(function(){
         makeArray.push($(this).val());
       });
      var url="http://example.com/results?Year="+yearArray.join()+"&Model="+makeArray.join();
        alert(url);
   });
});
```

Comment: it was mistake on answer. Name should be "Year" or "Make" - i have updated my answer . can you try this now

Comment: Yes , Please check it now

Comment: Check this link for live demo http://tpcg.io/UV1IHI . Click on Preview to run demo

Comment: Please upvote and mark correct if answer is helpful

Comment: Sir , your answer is correct but it has holes , can we make this [name=Year]:checked" dynamic ? so that i no longer have no declare another  var mothArray = []; if i wanted to add 
   <text>Month</text>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Month" value="choicefff">January<br>